# Can an AWS EC2 instance drop IAM policy permissions at runtime

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a group of EC2 instances that are granted permissions via an instance profile to read a secret from AWS Secret Manager. This is used to bootstrap the server, but after the bootstrapping is done it's possible for other users to run arbitrary jobs on this server.

Can I programmatically remove the IAM policy related to the secrets manager from the running instance during the bootstrap?

Otherwise, how can I get some ephemeral credentials working in the bootstrap phase (via `user_data` script) that can access the secret just the once and then not permit arbitrary jobs from being able to have access?

Comment: If using CloudFormation, take a look at [Retrieve an AWS Secrets Manager secret in an AWS CloudFormation resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/cfn-example_reference-secret.html) to see if fits. The deployment creds would need Secrets Manager access but the EC2 instance profile would not.

Comment: Thanks @jarmod but we're Terraform :)

Comment: [Possibly](https://blog.gruntwork.io/a-comprehensive-guide-to-managing-secrets-in-your-terraform-code-1d586955ace1#bebe) also supported with Terraform.

Comment: You could change your instance profile in the bootstrap script after doing whatever it is that needs elevated privileges (and note that you'd need to include the privilege to make this change): https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/associate-iam-instance-profile.html

Comment: @kdgregory I think I'm going to go with [diassociate-iam-instance-profile](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/disassociate-iam-instance-profile.html) instead as this way the permissions I need to give to the initial profile can include this and then it'll have nothing left over. It's OK for this instance to have no profile permissions.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by dropping privileges after the bootstrap is complete. In order to do this we need a few permissions added to the instance in the first place.

The following Terraform snippet shows an IAM policy that allows the instance to disassociate an instance profile. `DescribeIamInstanceProfileAssociations` is required to get the `association-id` that is required for the disassociate command.

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "instance-disassociate-iam-profile" {
    statement {
        sid = ""
        effect = "Allow"
        resources = ["*"]
        actions = [
            "ec2:DisassociateIamInstanceProfile",
            "ec2:DescribeIamInstanceProfileAssociations"
        ]
    }
}
```

With the permissions in place, the end of the bootstrap script can remove the instance profile associated with this instance.

```
# Downgrade the IAM role now that we've finished accessing the secrets manager :)
association_id=$(aws ec2 describe-iam-instance-profile-associations \
                     --filters 'Name=instance-id,Values='$(ec2metadata --instance-id) \
                     | jq -r '.IamInstanceProfileAssociations[0].AssociationId')
aws ec2 disassociate-iam-instance-profile --association-id ${association_id}
```

You may need more filters if you have multiple associations to figure out, etc. This shows how to remove an association where we only have a single association. As this is on ubuntu we use the `ec2metadata` command, but if you're on AL2 or similar you can use the `ec2-metadata` command instead.

Once the disassociation ocurrs, the permissions of the EC2 instance have been reduced:

```
$ aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id SUPER_SECRET

Unable to locate credentials. You can configure credentials by running "aws configure".
```